# Как дублировать элемент в строке?

Tags: vba

Есть задание, в котором нужно дублировать элементы отличные от какой-либо цифры. К примеру, строка — `ds2k17d9`, цифра — 7, все символы, кроме 7 должны быть дублированы.

Я написал код, но он не работает, и я не понимаю почему.

```
vhod = "2"
stroka = "835232"
For i = 1 To Len(stroka)
    L = Mid$(stroka, i, 1)
    If L <> vhod Then
        Zam = Replace(Zam, L, L & L)
    End If
Next i
MsgBox (Zam)
```

Answer (score 3):

Здесь Replace применять нельзя.
Почему?

Пример. Текст "*aba*".

```
Шаг1. Replace("aba", "a", "a" & "a") = "aabaa"
Шаг2. Replace("aabaa", "b", "b" & "b") = "aabbaa"
Шаг3. Replace("aabbaa", "a", "a" & "a") = "aaaabbaaaa"
```

Просматриваем каждый символ заданного слова и формируем новое слово:

```
Sub TakeOfSymbol()
Dim sSymbol As String, sMid As String
Dim sText As String, sStr As String
Dim j As Long
    sSymbol = "t": sText = "totem"

    For j = 1 To Len(sText) ' перебираем символы слова
        sMid = Mid$(sText, j, 1) ' извлекаем символ в переменную

        If sMid = sSymbol Then ' символ равен проверяемому
            sStr = sStr & sMid ' формируем новое слово
        Else
            sStr = sStr & sMid & sMid
        End If
    Next j

    MsgBox sStr
End Sub
```

*If* можно сократить:

```
sStr = sStr & sMid
If sMid <> sSymbol Then sStr = sStr & sMid
```

Answer (score 3):

> он не работает и я не понимаю почему

Код не работает потому, что цикл организован по НАЧАЛЬНОЙ длине строки - а она в процессе работы цикла увеличивается.

Простейшее решение - выполнить всё то же, но от конца строки, а не от начала, т,е.

```
For i = Len(stroka) To 1 Step -1
```

Это раз.

Теперь два - если в строке есть повторяющиеся символы - они будут удваиваться каждый раз, т.е. в итоге их вместо одного станет 2, потом 4, 8, 16 или больше - смотря сколько раз конкретный символ встречается... Нужно указывать для Replace точное место замены и количество замен (одна, есссно).

Ну и три. Переменная Zam нигде не определена и не получает начального значения. Даже если Option Explicit не включен, заменять что-то в пустой строке - занятие безнадёжное...

В общем, гораздо разумнее брать из исходной переменной по одному символу и добавлять к конечной переменной, изначально пустой. По одному, если это заданный символ, и по два, если нет:

```
For i = 1 to Len(source)
    destination = destination & mid(source, i, 1)
    if mid(source, i, 1) <> givenchar then
        destination = destination & mid(source, i, 1)
    end if
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub duplicate()
    Dim StrIn As String
    Dim StrOut As String
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim Twice As Boolean

    StrIn = "835*23*2"
    Symbol = "2"
    StrOut = ""

    If InStr(StrIn, Symbol) > 0 Then
        Twice = True
    Else
        Twice = False
    End If

    For i = 1 To Len(StrIn)
        Char = Mid(StrIn, i, 1)
        Select Case Char
            Case Symbol
                StrOut = StrOut & Char
            Case "*"
                StrOut = StrOut
            Case Else
                StrOut = StrOut & Char
                If Twice Then
                    StrOut = StrOut & Char
                End If
        End Select
    Next i

    MsgBox (StrOut)
End Sub
```